# How can I compare date of two rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, gridview

I have Gridview and Datasource like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [data.csv]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10" GridLines="Vertical" 
        Width="695px" Height="130px" onrowdatabound="GridView3_RowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="H" HeaderText="H" 
                SortExpression="H" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="115px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="V" HeaderText="V" 
                SortExpression="V" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="F" HeaderText="F" 
                SortExpression="F" dataformatstring="{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="180px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="V" HeaderText="V" 
                SortExpression="V" dataformatstring="{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}" >
            <HeaderStyle Width="180px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
```

I use csv file for data. I have to change backcolor if date value is old(2 hours).

I can do that for first date column like this:

```
 DateTime dt;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[1].Text, "dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm",
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                         DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   if (dt <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2))
   {
       if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("M"))
       {
           e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
       }
   }
```

If first date column values older than 2 hours, backcolor changing.

I need to do this for 2. date column. But compare to first date value. If second date value older than 2 hours according to the first date value, backcolor changing:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TimeSpan class to calculate the difference between to date. You can do this OnRowDataBound event, see below

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            //Checking the RowType of the Row  
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DateTime firstDateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
                DateTime secondDateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);

                 TimeSpan timespan = secondDateValue - firstDateValue; 

                if (timespan.Hours > 2)
                {
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can I use for Gridview rows?

Comment: @Ric I've edited the answer, please check if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it's work for me. But when date values like this(Hour and min 00), does not work: `09.09.2015 00:00`. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not compare days, just compare to hours. If older than 1 days, does not work if hours value not older than 2 hours.

Comment: Thank you. But it's getting error for Math: `Error 1 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Round(double)' and 'System.Math.Round(decimal)'` and for first 60: `Error 2 The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode`

Comment: I tried double and decimal before `diffInTicks` in `Math.Round`, but does not work.

Comment: Anyway, I use your old solution with timespan.TotalHours. It's work for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can put this when you populate your `DataGridView`

```
int index = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[colFirstDate.Name].Value = DateTime.Now;
        dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[colSecondDate.Name].Value = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);

        DateTime firstDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[colFirstDate.Name].Value);
        DateTime secondDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[colSecondDate.Name].Value);
        TimeSpan timespan = secondDate - firstDate;

        if (timespan.Hours > 2)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells[colFirstDate.Name].Style.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        }
```